# Asciio on Ubuntu, can't find export as .txt

Tags: linux, ubuntu, export, ascii-art

I just downloaded Asciio to my workstation running Ubuntu 14.04.
I created a pretty complex piece of ascii code in order to put as part of the documentation inside my code.

I can save files and open them (to edit later), but I can't export the file in order to put the ascii art in a code file (can't export as .txt)

I tried to open the editable file but it's binary so I can't see the ascii I created by doing that.

I installed Asciio with the following command: `sudo apt-get install asciio`.

I must be missing something because it can't be that you can't export ascii art from this. Plus, I saw in the documentation it suppose to show export in the context menu (Under 'exporting to ASCII'): http://manned.org/App::Asciio/61eec608

Anyone had this problem before?

thank!

Answer (score 1):

Try "Save As" and add ".txt" to your filename.
it's worked for me!